# the intersection of a real form and a parabolic subalgebra

Tags: semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a complex  semisimple Lie algebra, $\mathfrak g_0$
a  real form and $\tau$ the conjugation of  $\mathfrak g$ with respect to $\mathfrak g_0$.
Real Lie algebra $\mathfrak g_{0}$ is called a real form of a complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ if $\mathfrak g$ is the complexification of $\mathfrak g_{0}$.
Now we fix a  [parabolic subalgebra](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Parabolic_subalgebra) $\mathfrak p$ of
$\mathfrak g$. I want to show that $\mathfrak g_{0} \cap \mathfrak p$ is a  real form of  $\mathfrak p \cap \tau\mathfrak p$. I'm completely stuck on how to start this question. Any help and comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $A \in \mathfrak{p} \cap \tau(\mathfrak{p})$ one has $$2 A=(A+\tau(A))+(A-\tau(A)),$$ where the first summand is contained in $\mathfrak{p} \cap \mathfrak{g}_{0}$ and the second one gets into that subspace after multiplication by $i$. In fact, this argument is valid for  any
complex Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathfrak{g}$.